# Who would be legally responsible for any possible US presidential election hack?

Tags: united-states, voting, presidential-election

There are claims that Russian hackers tried altering the US presidential election data، Most of these claims, as far as I know, that has no verifiable evidence.

If this happened, who (person or organisation) would be legally responsible?

Comment: This question's really weird, as it doesn't seem like a request for actual information so much as to subtly get the suggestion out there that people should blame Obama rather than anyone else, e.g. the hackers or those who benefited from it.  This gets weirder in that it's from a throwaway account, and then immediately answered by another throwaway account.  Overall, it reads like someone's trying to do PR.

Comment: @Nat Although I agree the question is poor [we must assume good faith unless the user proves otherwise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55822/do-we-need-assume-good-faith-like-wikipedia) Therefore I would not reccomend deletion but rather re-editing.

Comment: @SleepingGod The recent edit has significantly improved the quality of this question, so that does seem like a viable route.  To note it, I don't think that the presumption of good faith applies in this case.  A single-use unregistered account that doesn't come back to address issues falls under the "_greatest sin_" that Jeff Atwood mentioned in his answer, while the other answer discusses these as "_maliciously lazy, often "fix my code for me" questions_".  It'd be different if the user had attempted to update their question or respond to comments.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of law, the hacker (Russia) is legally responsible.

None of the reported hacks were actual hacks against the election process, but if they were, such an act is an act of war, as would be any other state sponsored act to interfere with the lawful succession of government. As for the infodumps from the Democratic National Convention, that's still Russia, but civil violations by a nation state are hard to pursue.

What you actually do about it is another story.